# python3 numpy: too many indices for array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a value, just like:

```
a = np.array({'a':1})
```

Then, I want to get the dict from a. But error happens when I use a[0]:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I have a look at the shape of a:

```
>>> a.shape
()
```

So, how to get the value from a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it like this,

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
a.item()['a']
# 1
```

Comment: `a[()]` is another way of accessing the element inside an 0d array.

Answer (score 2):

You should create your array with list;

```
a = np.array([{'a':1}])
```

Comment: In fact, I use numpy to save a dict. And after np.load, the value look like  what I gave. The value is not created by me, but by np.load

Answer (score 1):

galmeriol is right. Go for as he has suggested.

```
>>> a.all()
{'a': 1}
>>>> a.all()['a']
1
```